# How to check whether the user cleared the application running state in background in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone application in which I am using autologin. So I am storing the credentials in local and doing the autologin.I have a logout button in the application in which I am popping back to login controller in my stack. But if the user clears the app in the background (by doubleclicking the Home button) then when he tries to logout in my app, there is no login view controller on the stack (because of autologin). Then the logout button doesn't work. Can anybody help me in tackling this situation? I am logging out like this:

```
   NSArray *array1 = [del.navigationController viewControllers];
   NSLog(@"%@",[del.navigationController viewControllers]);
   [del.navigationController popToViewController:[array1 objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Comment: How are you adding loginView when user logs out, please paste the code.

Comment: Do you see the log in console for `NSLog(@"%@",[del.navigationController viewControllers]);`? I have feeling that some how these code doesn't trigger for the condition you mentioned above.

Comment: @OhhMee when the app is running in the backgroung this is ok.but if the user stops the running in backgroung then that login view is not in the stack.so that i am asking how we can check it?whether the app is running or stopped in the background.?thats my question?

Comment: We can't do that, no API is provided to check that. You can do it on jailbroken phones only.

Comment: @OhhMee is it needs to be considered in the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  NSArray *array1 = [del.navigationController viewControllers];
   NSLog(@"%@",[del.navigationController viewControllers]);
   [del.navigationController popToViewController:[array1 objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

`[array1 objectAtIndex:0]`  in that case wont be your login view .

So you can keep a condition like this :

```
  UIViewController *vw = (UIViewController *) [array1 objectAtIndex:0];
  if([vw isKindOfClass:[login class])
    [del.navigationController popToViewController:[array1 objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
  else
  {
   // init ur login class and push that to nav stack. 
   }
```